# DeadlineExceededException on /_ah/warmup and general appengine app failure

Tags: google-app-engine

Suddenly my app started raising DeadlineExceededException from all servlets/tasks. I also noticed that on top of everything there is /_ah/warmup servlet with a latency of 151 seconds (151154ms). Is that normal? I don't think that over night my whole app code got worse.

Is anybody else experiencing problems like this? Is there a solution?

Thanks,
Cristian.

Comment: The app is using High Repllication Datastore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a tonne of people complaining about this on the mailing list.  It's mostly apps on the M/S datastore.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine/js5CeRWLQZ0

Comment: I just switched to HRD and the issues disappeared.  Definitely a scary couple of days...

Comment: Then I look forward to more scary days :(

Comment: We are a small startup and if this thing goes on I'm afraid we're going to lose all customers...

Comment: The best thing to do is either post a production issue (though there probably are a bunch already), or get help on the forum.  I don't think these issues are being addressed on StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm in the same trouble, @NicanorCristianBabula :(  If it's still happening tomorrow we're going to look at switching platforms